# How to calculate this integral using Cauchy's theorem?

Tags: complex-integration, cauchy-riemann-equations

The integral is:

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{-\sin\theta}\cos(\theta+\cos\theta)d\theta$$

My first thoughts were to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar coordinates to show that the function is regular over the integration domain and therefore applying Cauchy's Theorem directly. However, since the function is real, it's imaginary part, $v$, equals $0$. With that, the CR equations don't seem to hold.

Any ideas/hints?

EDIT: I forgot to add a minus sign.

Comment: Write the outermost cosine as the real part of a complex exponential, then spot an antiderivative.

Comment: However, the integral seems to give zero for simple symmetry reasons

Comment: @Giulio Looking at the graph, yes, but I'm asked to solve it using Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: @J.G. That seems like a good method, but this problem comes from a chapter before Laurent series are introduced, so I suppose it can be solved purely using Cauchy's theorem?

Comment: I've edited my comment to address that. You may find the substitution $z=e^{i\theta}$ helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\,\mathrm{d}}$You may rewrite: $$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-\sin\theta}\cos(\theta+\cos(\theta))\d\theta&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\theta}e^{i\cos\theta-\sin\theta}\d \theta+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-i\theta}e^{-(i\cos\theta+\sin\theta)}\d \theta\\&=\frac{1}{2i}\oint_{|z|=1}e^{iz}\d z+\frac{1}{2i}\oint_{|z|=1}e^{-iz}\d z\\&=-i\oint_{|z|=1}\cos(z)\d z\\&=0\quad\text{by holomorphy, Cauchy Integral Theorem}\end{align}$$

Where the contours $z=e^{it}$ and $z=e^{-it}$ were substituted (a double negative preserves orientation in the second integral).

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(\theta)=e^{-\sin\theta}\cos(\theta+\cos\theta)$. Note that
$$
f(\pi-\theta)=e^{-\sin\theta}\cos(\pi-\theta-\cos\theta)=-e^{-\sin\theta}\cos(\theta+\cos\theta)=-f(\theta).
$$
So
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(\theta)\,d\theta=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta)\,d\theta+\int_{\pi}^{3\pi}f(\theta)\,d\theta=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}[f(\theta)+f(\pi-\theta)]\,d\theta=0.
$$